# Transition from gobal Vue instance to app breaks import dependency

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm looking at migrating a Vue 2 app to Vue 3 and ran into a problem. The Vue 2 app used to start with importing a whole lot of components and directives:

```
// these components register to the global Vue instance
import {ComponentA} from './componenta';
import {directiveA} from './directivea';


// create app (after the components are registered)
new Vue({...})
```

This worked fine, but when changing this code to Vue3, the app instance is now created instead. This instance isn't actually available when the global directives and components are imported.

What's the recommended way for dealing with this? I can't reorder the imports to the bottom of the file as webpack bundles them always at the top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with a solution that imports the `app` instance before component registration/definition (which occur within the component file) in an attempt to keep the current structure.

```
import {app} from './instance';
import './components/popupwindow';
import App from './app.vue';

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```
// instance.js

import {createApp} from 'vue';
const app = createApp();
export {app};
```

```
// popupwindow.vue

import {app} from '../instance';

// component registration+definition here (for global components only)
app.component('popup', {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of imports does not matter in your case - what matters is the order of the JavaScript statements that follow the `import` section.
You should first create the `app` instance and only then register your global components to this instance - as explained in https://learnvue.co/2020/08/how-to-register-a-vue3-global-component/

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import PopupWindow from './components/PopupWindow'
import App from "./App.vue"

const app = createApp(App)

app.component('PopupWindow', PopupWindow) // global registration - can be used anywhere

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: I ended up importing another file before running any of the other code which creates and exports the `app` instance. that way, all other component imports can access this `app` instance.

Comment: Your example doesn't work in my case because the `app.component('Popup')` call would happen as part of an `import {Popup} from './popupcomponent'` before `createApp()`. Now with adding a `import {app} from './app'` prior to this import, the `app` instance already exists for the component imports.

Comment: `import` statements are not a "sequence of commands" - you can import your components in the order of A, B, C and then register them in the order of C, A, B or B, A, C. However, if the code in `popupcomponent` relies on the existence of the global variable `app` and tries to register itself into this instance - then this is a different story and certainly not a recommended architecture.

Comment: What are you suggesting instead? To define all components in one file after creating an `app` instance? Certainly not...

Comment: You seem to confuse the component definition (and every SFC is essentially just a definition) with component registration. When you import the default export from an SFC - you are actually importing a simple JavaScript object. The only rule here is that you should register your global components into the `app` instance **before** mounting it (the `app`) onto the DOM.

Comment: I'd like to do the registration and definition in one step. Global components "know" that they are global, so I don't see a point to unnecessarily separate these two. Anyway, my approach of importing the components works fine (in fact only `import './popupcomponent'` is called to do the registration/definition). The component instance isn't required as per my previous explanation.

Comment: Okay - then update your question with your solution so that it is useful to other people in the future.

Comment: fair enough - thanks for your help. this convo helped.